# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when using pd.query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['John Smith', 'bbla', 'A B']})
```

I tried running the following query over it:

```py
df.query('x.str.count(" ") == 1')
```

And it results in:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

If I replace `1` with a string it works fine (though obviously returns an empty `DataFrame`). If I replace it with another `Series` or anything else it works too.

If I just want to compare some series to a scalar, that is ok too. Why can't I compare the result of `.count(" ")` to a number?

**Update**

For some reason, this works:

```py
df.query('x.str.count(" ") == [1]')
```

If anything I would expect this to fail because now I'm comparing collections of different size. Obviously, some implicit broadcasting is taking place here but I don't see why the same couldn't happen for the scalar version.

Comment: The code works for me.

Comment: This is what the code outputs for me: `print('            x\n0  John Smith\n2         A B')`

Comment: Try running your code in a new python session (if it's interactive). Otherwise, could you show more of your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare some series to a scala"?

Comment: That's all the code there is. I get the same error both locally and on Google Colab

Comment: What is your pandas version? (and numpy)

Comment: `pandas==1.2.4 / 1.1.5`, `numpy==1.20.1 / 1.19.5`

Comment: Still just not able to reproduce. Using all/any of those versions, it all just works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the `numexpr` package is installed in your environment.  It provides one of the possible backends for pandas' query function.

See [similar issue here on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29027)

Your options are to uninstall it or avoid using query in this instance

Comment: Do you have any idea what happens behind the scenes for `[1]` to work but not `1`?

Comment: Thats a question for someone with in-depth knowledge of [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), which is not me unfortunately.